# No LastEvaluatedKey when using ScanOndexForward

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I’ve got a dynamo table filled with thousands of entries.

When I query, with ScanIndexForward = True, I get a LastEvaluatedKey that I can use to get the next batch (1mb limit)

But when I use ScanIndexForward = False, I don’t have a LastEvaluatedKey value.

Is this default behaviour?

**Query in question**

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('dev2')

    if sort_desc == '':
        sort_desc = False

    if last_key_date == '':
        response = table.query(
            ScanIndexForward=bool(sort_desc),
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('exp_ID').eq(experiment_id)
        )
    else:
        response = table.query(
            ScanIndexForward=bool(sort_desc),
            ExclusiveStartKey={
                "Time": last_key_date,
                "exp_ID": experiment_id
            },
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('exp_ID').eq(experiment_id)
        )

    return response
```

**Table Structure**

```
Primary key = exp_ID
Sort key = Time
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share more info ? - exact query, table sample/structure, indexes

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: are you using the ExclusiveStartKey in your query? if so, it may be at the end of the table, scanning in one order may return a lot of results, scanning in the other will return just a few.